# what is the max number css rules I can specify in style sheet per browser

Tags: css

what is the max number css rules I can specify in style sheet per browser.

Comment: Are you hitting a problem related to this?

Answer (score 21):

Internet Explorer 6-9 have a few reported limits:

- Any rules after the first 4,095 are ignored
- Any stylesheets included via `@import`, `<link>` or `<style>`, are ignored after the first 31
- `@import` statements nested 4 or more levels deep are ignored

These limits are outlined in [KB 262161](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/developer/browsers/development-website/css-styles-webpage-renders-wrongly).  In IE10 these limits [were significantly raised](https://web.archive.org/web/20160203060157/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/14/10164546.aspx) to:

- A stylesheet may contain up to 65,534 rules
- A document may use up to 4,095 stylesheets
- `@import` nesting no longer has its own limit

There are no such reported limits for other browsers, but in theory any of them could run into performance issues with a large number of unoptimised CSS rules.

Various sources:

http://simple.procoding.net/2009/02/20/internet-explorer-limits-number-of-external-css-files-to-32/
http://joshua.perina.com/africa/gambia/fajara/post/internet-explorer-css-file-size-limit
http://am-blog.no-ip.org/BlogEngine/post/2010/03/24/CSS-File-Size-Limit-in-Internet-Explorer-6-7-8.aspx

Comment: I just hit the max rules per stylesheet issue when using a CSS preprocesser with "mixins" (LESS) :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about how many css includes you can do?  IE does have a maximum of 32 ([source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/ad1b6e88-bbfa-4cc4-9e95-3889b82a7c1d)) or maybe [31](http://john.albin.net/css/ie-stylesheets-not-loading).

However it sounds like you are asking if there is a maximum amount of styles you can include in a single .css file, and I am not aware of any limit in that respect.