# Cannot add further CSS rules to WordPress style.css

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working on creating my first custom theme in underscores.

My issue is I can no longer add styles to style.css.
I can edit existing style rules in there, or add to classes that already exist.

But for any new styles I am inserting for new pages and so forth, I am forced to add to a new CSS I made and called 'custom.css'.

I created this to add styles to bootstrap.

When I view source 'style.css' is loading above 'custom.css' on pages.

And yet, when I add new styles to style.css it changes nothing on page.

Anyone know why this could be occuring?

Comment: Did you tried to clear browser cache? Or CTRL+F5 refresh?

Comment: Yes.  I've also tried multiple browsers with different browser caches.

Comment: maybe Varnish is problem.. check last post here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/stylecss-not-updating-2

Comment: Thank you but I do not think this is the issue.  I can edit existing lines in style.css but cannot add any new ones (I've only tried to the bottom of my style.css, maybe I will experiment with it).  Also I am on localhost playing around with things not on a web server.

Comment: hmm thats strange.. so you open file in editor add new styles, save it and after opening it again those styles are not there?

Comment: See response below... I added new styles to the top as opposed to the bottom of my style.css and they worked fine.  It must have been issue with my style.css being too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your css file is too long. Add your _s code to the file _s.css and start the style.css file with:

```
/*
Theme Name: mytheme
Author: myname
Author URI: myurl
Version: 1.0.0
Text Domain: mythemename
*/

@import url('_s.css')
```

Comment: My style.css is around 1100 lines.  I did not know that was a thing, for a style.css to be too long.

I can edit the CSS in another css file via enqueue, or import CSS fine, I am just wondering why I can no longer add styles to style.css (but can edit existing styles just fine)

Comment: Ah... so I placed my style at the very top of my style.css and it is working!  But when I place my style rules at the bottom of style.css, it does not work.   This must have been the issue, style.css being too long.  Thank you!

Comment: Do you know why this occurred?  According to other sources [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406265/what-is-the-max-number-css-rules-i-can-specify-in-style-sheet-per-browser) the max length of a css file is no where near 1000 lines, which is about where it stopped for me...

Comment: I think it is the browser/textarea in WordPress that has problems with displaying and editing large files. I use the underscore_s theme too and having a large style.css made editing and updating VERY slow. That is why I came up with this solution. This seemed like (sort of) the same problem. I am glad it works!